# Spring Data JPA- ignore parameter if it has a null value in between condition

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, hql

I'm trying to write the following query

```
@Query(value = " " + "SELECT new om.gov.moh.ereferral.model.dto.ClinicalReferralStatisticsDto("
            + "SUM(CASE WHEN B.id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS OPD," + "SUM(CASE WHEN  B.id = 2 THEN 1 END)     AS IPD,"
            + "SUM(CASE WHEN B.id = 3 THEN 1 END)     AS DC," + "SUM(CASE WHEN B.id = 4 THEN 1 END )    AS PROC,"
            + " SUM(CASE WHEN B.id = 5 THEN 1 END)     AS SURGERY , SUM (CASE WHEN B.id IN (1,2,3,4,5)THEN 1 END)     AS Total)"
            + "FROM RefTbAppTransaction A, RefVwVisitType B "
            + "WHERE A.reqVisitType.id = B.id AND A.toEstCode = :toEstCode "
            + "AND A.referralDate BETWEEN TRUNC(:fromDate) AND TRUNC(:toDate) " 
            + "and (COALESCE(:fromEstCode, null) is null or A.fromEstCode in :fromEstCode)"
            )
```

Now it's work fine but I want if  **fromDate** is null to bring all data till **toDate** and if **toDate** is null to bring all data from selected date in **fromDate** till current date and if both are null to ignore the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try next pattern

```sql
where (:fromDate is null or A.referralDate >= :fromDate)
and (:toDate is null or A.referralDate <= :toDate)
```

Comment: still it's give me ` "A Null Point Exception has occured ..."`

Comment: It is different problem. I can't help you with that.